# Django login not working with custom user

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a django project with a custom user (its like [this](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/) one so I can use email instead of username).

I am creating an AJAX login but it keeps returning a 500 error which I am finding hard to debug. My code in the view is:

```
@require_AJAX
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email_address']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print email, password
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        print user
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                print 'starting to work'
                login(request, user)
                print 'it worked'

                response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code':'ok'}), content_type='application/json')
            else:
                response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code':'inactive'}), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            print 'user is none'
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code':'notok'}), content_type='application/json') 
        return response
```

All the parts work fine except for the one where the user is an active user and then the login(request, user) seems to fail for some reason (I get 'starting to work' printed to console but not 'it worked'.

Does anyone know why this might be or can they suggest how I can get the exception to be shown in the console?

Comment: set `DEBUG=True` to see a page with stack trace

Comment: Yes debug is on but because it is an AJAX call, it doesn't show, it just returns a 500 error to the AJAX script and I don't get the stack trace.

Comment: use chrome inspector to view the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because I have named the view login, which is the same as the login() function builtin to django. Silly. Renamed it to ajax_login and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your Django application is throwing an Error 500 because of the `login(request, user)` call. The reason for it failing is because you are passing in two arguments (`request` and `user`) even though the method definition only expects one argument to be passed in (which is `request` as specified in `def login(request)`). There seems to be something wrong with the logic I believe as you probably wouldn't expect a recursive call at this point anyway.

Instead, I suggest you make use of the Django authentication system. It provides appropriate methods to authenticate users, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

You should have a closer look at the Django documentation where I have taken this code snippet from. There is a more sophisticated example on how to use the authentication system: [Authenticating Users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users).

Comment: I use authenticate, just above where I use login() and most of my code came from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login but your answer led me to the reason for the error (see my answer) so thanks. I am very silly.

Comment: Indeed, you do use authenticate! I didn't notice it, sorry! I'm glad it helped to resolve the issue though.